# How can I easily serialize Java graph to/from JSON?

Tags: java, json, serialization

I am struggling to find a library that will serialise a simple graph of Java objects to/from JSON (no need for circular refs or anything). I don't want to have Java class names in the output but including an extra "@type": "foo" property is fine. It must work with untyped collections and maps. I expect to have to do something like mapper.registerType(MyClass.class, "foo") to specify the type mappings but the library must take it from there. Anyone know of such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Genson](http://code.google.com/p/genson/) it provides full databinding support, with polymorphic and untyped objects and has many other features.

```
// this defines aliases for classes, if you don't care of class names being
// serialized then just enabled type ser/deser using builder.setWithClassMetadata(true)
Genson genson = new Genson.Builder()
                            .addAlias("person", Person.class)
                            .addAlias("other", Some.class)
                           .create();

// serialize using with type information
String json = genson.serialize(object);

// deserializing to an unkown type based on the type information in the json string
genson.deserialize(json, Object.class);
```

Comment: This is the shizzle! Took 2 mins to get it working and it does what I need!

Answer (score 2):

Jackson should be able to handle what it is that you are trying to do.  Check out the examples from this link, most specifically #4 for polymorphic type deserialization

[Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)

[Polymorphic Type Handling](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization)

[Examples](http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html)

Comment: Jackson works, but I personally find Jackson awful to work with and MUCH prefer GSON. That said, Jackson does better fit this question, so upvote anyway.

Comment: I tried Jackson but couldn't get it to do what I wanted. I also found that example but it seems things have changed since then. The mapper.enableDefaultTypeing() thing almost works. I spent a lot of time fiddling with it (the code is complex!) and ended up posting my SO question. This really shouldn't be hard!

Comment: Added a link to Polymorphic Type Handling from current jackson version wiki.  See if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Do you search something like this?

http://code.google.com/p/json-io/

> json-io consists of two main classes, a reader (JsonReader) and a
>   writer (JsonWriter). There is a 3rd rigorous test class
>   (TestJsonReaderWriter). json-io eliminates the need for using
>   ObjectInputStream / ObjectOutputStream to serialize Java and instead
>   uses the JSON format.

...

> Usage
>
> json-io can be used directly on JSON Strings or with Java's Streams.

Comment: From what I can see from the docs it puts fully qualified class names into the JSON: "@type":"package.class". Do you know if it is possible to change this?

Comment: Just looking for a solution, if its possible.